# Windows 8 App. Back Button not working

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm using a new item Basic Template with the app name and back button.
It is being used inside of a "Blank" project.

However, the back button is not responding to touch events.

This following is code that was generated. The back button just disappears.

```
<Button x:Name="backButton" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" Click="GoBack"/>
```

I even tried making my own Click Handle and tried navigating myself with.

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```

However that isn't working either. Probably due to something that auto generated because I can create a button myself and wire it up for that (so I'm really trying to stick with the Templates).

Any ideas please?

Edit:
I found it really odd none of the Navigation is working. After drilling some more it appears to be something with LayoutAwarePage. I'm missing something here. Will post updates.

Edit: Sorry about that. I added the event click listeners back in (I must have removed that copying around). However that still does not fix my issue. I tried setting the back button to the "GoBack" function and when you hit the back button it just disappears. I also tried creating my own method and trying to navigate myself and still did not work.

Comment: Do you mean the Blank App template? Or are you talking about a Visual Basic project?

Comment: No. You are able to create a new item and choose "Basic Page" as a template. However, I did create the project using a "Blank App"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to write any of your own code to enable the back button, as it ties into the underlying navigation framework automatically. If there is a page in the back stack to navigate to, the back button will be enabled.

What you are missing, from what I can see, is that if you start your app on the Basic page that you added, there's nothing in the back stack of the navigation framework for you to navigate to.

I tested your scenario using the following steps:

1. I created a new C#/XAML Windows Store app using the Blank App template.
2. Then added a new Basic page (BasicPage1.xaml).
3. Opened MainPage.xaml, and added a Button to the page.
4. Double-clicked the button, and added the following code to the click event handler:

   this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage1));

Ran the project, and the back button worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks. It's looking like I'm going to have to start over as well. I might have changed something important, don't know what, while learning how to program Windows.

Comment: Didn't find out why it wasn't happening. I just recreated a new project and as calling base.NavigateTo everything was working.

Comment: @frank, can you please elaborate? I'm running into the same issue. What do you mean with "as calling base.NavigateTo"?

Comment: This issue was really old, but I resolved it by creating a new project and starting over. I remember that everything seemed to be wired fine, in fact I don't remember changing anything but something must have gotten changed to disable the functionality.

Answer (score 4):

You need an `Click` event handler on the button. `Click="GoBack"`

```
<Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
```

`GoBack` function is available in `LayoutAwarePage` which is most likely the base class of your page, if not make sure it is. `LayoutAwarePage` class resides inside `Project\Common`

Comment: Thanks. I did have that, but must have removed it posting. Doubled checked that its in there, however it's still not working. From what I see the "GoBack" function must be overridden which means that I shouldn't have to create it. Just let the button call it. Correct?

Comment: `GoBack` function is available in `LayoutAwarePage` which is most likely the base class of your page, if not make sure it is. `LayoutAwarePage` class resides inside `Project\Common`

Comment: @Mayank Your comment about `LayoutAwarePage` is important. This should be a part of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the XAML markup that I see, there is no `Click` event handler tied to the button, so no action is taken unless you hook it to one.

Comment: I tried using the "GoBack" method and creating a my own listener that called navigate. Still no luck. Can it have something to do with how I set the project up?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this approach appears to take code from the Basic page. Could you confirm that you are inheriting from LayoutAwarePage and not from Page? Otherwise GoBack is not implemented in this way. Also, you cannot GoBack if you have not navigated from this page in the first place, from another. And, finally (just brainstorming here), you cannot GoBack if you got to this page by setting the Frame itself and not the page (in the previous location). This would clear the navigation history.

And, also, can you confirm this does not work?

```
this.Frame.GoBack();
```

Best of luck!

Comment: I am sure that I am extending LayoutAwarePage.
I tried making my mainpage extend from LayoutWarePage (as it is Page now) and that broke my navigation as well. The problem is defiantly something to do with LayoutAwarePage. Perhaps something is just mis-configured (not sure where). I may just have to create a new project and try again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Im making my back buttons like this:

XAML code. In this case LoginPage.xaml.

`<Button x:Name="ButtonGoBack" Click="ButtonGoBack_OnClick" Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"/>`

C# code in LoginPage.xaml.cs

```
private void ButtonGoBack_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.GoBack();
    }
```

Comment: Could you pleaseexplain more your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue as Frank. I found my problem to be that I overrided the OnNavigatedTo handler without calling the base class's (LayoutAwarePage) handler also. This meant LayoutAwarePage wasn't setting its _pageKey member variable which it uses in its OnNavigatedFrom handler.

Hope this helps others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. I know nothing could've changed in my code so I checked the project properties. In Common Properties->References I noticed an anomaly, there have been some resources that was never there, ( all I should have in that project is SQLite for Windows RunTime). I then deleted the unwanted resource and fixed the navigation problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you used

```
Frame.SetNavigationState("1,0");
```

you removed the back stack entry , so the back button will not working .